# Replace all zeros in array with elements of another array

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting, sudoku

Say I've got an array like this:

```
array_1 =  [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0]
```

and another one like this:

```
array_2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

How can I create an array like this, such that each 0 in the `array_1` is replaced by the first and subsequent elements of the `array_2`?:

`[4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 6]`

That is, every time we encounter a `0` in the first array, we'd like to replace it with the result of `array_2.shift`.

Comment: Well, you have half of the answer right there. Use `map` and `shift`, with some conditionals on top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one is shorter but the *shift* method it will modify array_2 in-place.

```
array_1.map {|x| x == 0 ? array_2.shift : x}
```

The following uses an enumerator object with external iteration and will not modify any of the original arrays.

```
e = array_2.each
array_1.map {|x| x == 0 ? e.next : x}
```

Comment: Even though the OP mentioned array_2.shift, it still should be noted that this mutates `array_2`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, iterate and shift when you encounter a 0

```
array_1.each_with_index do |val, i|
  array_1[i] = array_2.shift if val == 0
end
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The question calls for a new array was to be created (rather than mutating `array_1`). Moreover, even though the OP mentioned `array_2.shift`, it still should be noted that this mutates `array_2` as well.