# Merge array at specific index in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need a method which returns a merged array starting a specified index. I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801516/how-do-you-add-an-array-to-another-array-in-ruby-and-not-end-up-with-a-multi-dim), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274802/replace-all-zeros-in-array-with-elements-of-another-array/38274957) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978413/merge-arrays-in-ruby-rails) without cracking it.

I can see that this concatenates but I want to update the array not simply combine them:

```
@a1 = [0,0,0,0,0]

a2 = [1,1]

def update_array(new_array)
  @a1.push(*new_array)  
end

update_array(a2)
```

I'd like the output to be something like:

```
#[0,1,1,0,0] or [0,0,0,1,1]
```

Depending on the index specified.

Comment: Where are you specifying the indexes?

Comment: I haven't in this method because I'm not sure how to. The method should specify the index somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the normal element assignment, [`Array#[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) and pass in the `start` and `length` parameters:

> Element Assignment — Sets the element at index, **or replaces a subarray from the start index for length elements**, or replaces a subarray specified by the range of indices.

(emphasis mine) So, for instance:

```
@a1 = [0,0,0,0,0]
a2 = [1,1]
@a1[1, a2.length] = a2
@a1 # => [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
@a1 = [0,0,0,0,0]
@a1[@a1.length - a2.length, a2.length] = a2
@a1 # => [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays have a method which does that: [insert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-insert)

```
a1 = [0,0,0,0,0]
a2 = [1,1]

a1.insert(1, *a2) # => [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I need to update each array element #=> [0, 1, 1, 0, 0] rather than just combine them